# Customer Community - Mobile Navigation Menu Item - Conditional Display

Tags: customer-community, mobile

We have a customer community built using "Customer Service" template. Can we display a navigation menu item, based on some condition for mobile users, who are using community on a mobile browser?

We have a custom navigation menu for desktop users implemented using a lightning component & in that, we can easily add conditions to display or not-display a menu item. This works fine for tablet users also, But the problem is only for mobile users.

Comment: If your conditions are based on something to do with the user's information (e.g. a field on their User/Contact records), you may be able to use Audiences to restrict visibility to some of the pages. Then SF hides the navigation links as appropriate.

Comment: @Aidan For mobile browser view of community, i don't believe we can use audiences. Plz correct if wrong.